# Path and Directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

On jupyternotebook I'm trying to create a path but i'm constantly getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

The code i have made is the one below:

```py
path = 'C:\Users\nadee\Desktop\Pictures'  
os.chdir(path)
```

I have tried adding r for my code and the `\\`:

```py
path = r'C:\Users\nadee\Desktop\Pictures'  
os.chdir(path)

path ='C:\\Users\\nadee\\Desktop\\Pictures'  ​
os.chdir(path)
```

But using these gets me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\nadee\\Desktop\\Pictures'
```

I don't think it is an error in pathway because i got it from file explorer:

```
C:\Users\nadee\Desktop\Pictures
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The version with doubled backslashes should work. You can also use forward slash or a raw string.

Comment: try `/` instead of `"\"`

Comment: You can use either double-backslashes, or `r"..."` with single backslashes, or forward slashes.  The lesson here is that you do not have a folder called `Pictures` on your desktop.  The standard `Pictures` folder is at the same level as `Desktop`, not below it, as in `C:/Users/nadee/Pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` is used to change directory. Here you want to create a path, you can use

```py
os.makedirs(path)
```